# Displaying two attributes in different tables under a single column in a dataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I need to display two different attributes from two different tables (in the same database) under a single column in a single dataGridView.

In my instance, I have `Invoice1`, `AccountName1`, `Pay_Amount1` attributes in Payment_Details table, and `Invoice2`, `AccountName2`, `Pay_Amount2` attributes in Receivable_Details table (The reason these same type of attributes are in two different tables instead of one is they are used to display separately in another form). I need to take `Invoice1` and `Invoice2` and display both under "Invoice" column in a single dataGridView. The same goes to `AccountName` and `Pay_Amount`.

Is this possible, if so, how? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest two solutions to solve it

s1:
you can join two different tables out of application(for example by creating a view in database) then bind it into grid

s2:
also you can join tables in back end(server side code) and bind its result into grid.
try it and tell me if it worked

Comment: Thank you for the response. Will try that out.